# Dynamically updated floorplan/asset register in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'd like to create a combined asset register and office floorplan in Excel 2010.

Ideally it would have one data sheet with rows containing: ethernet socket number, room number, building, user name (or device role, for hotdesks), computer or device asset number; and a second map sheet with our building floorplans as the background image (already exists as PNG) and floating text boxes showing the user and device in each position.

I wanted to use the ethernet socket nos as the key data, because they are the least likely data type to change. So what I need to do for each text box on the map sheet, is identify the row on the data sheet that contains a particular socket no, and call the user name and device asset number from that row to display on the map.

Can anyone tell me how to do this please, or point to instructions? Suggestions to use other software (Access?) also welcome, if this will be hard to achieve in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Microsoft Visio for something like this.